# Spring-Integration: Tcp Server Response not sent on Exception

Tags: spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration

I migrated a legacy tcp server code into spring-boot and added spring-intergration (annotation based) dependencies to handle tcp socket connections.

My inbound Channel is tcpIn() , outbound Channel is serviceChannel() and i have created a custom Channel [ exceptionEventChannel() ] to hold exception event messages.

I have a custom serializer/Deserialier method (ByteArrayLengthPrefixSerializer() extends AbstractPooledBufferByteArraySerializer), and a MessageHandler @ServiceActivator method to send response back to tcp client.

```
//SpringBoot 2.0.3.RELEASE, Spring Integration 5.0.6.RELEASE

package com.test.config;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.IntegrationComponentScan;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Transformer;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.event.inbound.ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.IpHeaders;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpReceivingChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.*;
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.TcpDeserializationExceptionEvent;
import org.springframework.integration.router.ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException;

import java.io.IOException;

@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class TcpConfiguration {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Value("${tcp.connection.port}")
    private int tcpPort;

    @Bean
    TcpConnectionEventListener customerTcpListener() {
        return new TcpConnectionEventListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel tcpIn() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel serviceChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "errorChannel")
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel errorChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel exceptionEventChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public ByteArrayLengthPrefixSerializer byteArrayLengthPrefixSerializer() {
        ByteArrayLengthPrefixSerializer byteArrayLengthPrefixSerializer = new ByteArrayLengthPrefixSerializer();
        byteArrayLengthPrefixSerializer.setMaxMessageSize(98304); //max allowed size set to 96kb
        return byteArrayLengthPrefixSerializer;
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory tcpNetServerConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory tcpServerCf = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(tcpPort);
        tcpServerCf.setSerializer(byteArrayLengthPrefixSerializer());
        tcpServerCf.setDeserializer(byteArrayLengthPrefixSerializer());
        return tcpServerCf;

    }

    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter tcpReceivingChannelAdapter() {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        adapter.setConnectionFactory(tcpNetServerConnectionFactory());
        adapter.setOutputChannel(tcpIn());
        adapter.setErrorChannel(exceptionEventChannel());
        return adapter;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "exceptionEventChannel", outputChannel = "serviceChannel")
    public String handle(Message<MessagingException> msg) {
        //String unfilteredMessage = new String(byteMessage, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        System.out.println("-----------------EXCEPTION ==> " + msg);
        return msg.toString();
    }

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "errorChannel", outputChannel = "serviceChannel")
    public String transformer(String msg) {
        //String unfilteredMessage = new String(byteMessage, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        System.out.println("-----------------ERROR ==> " + msg);
        return msg.toString();
    }


    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "serviceChannel")
    @Bean
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler out(AbstractServerConnectionFactory cf) {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpSendingMessageHandler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        tcpSendingMessageHandler.setConnectionFactory(cf);
        return tcpSendingMessageHandler;
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationListener<TcpDeserializationExceptionEvent> listener() {
        return new ApplicationListener<TcpDeserializationExceptionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void onApplicationEvent(TcpDeserializationExceptionEvent tcpDeserializationExceptionEvent) {
                exceptionEventChannel().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(tcpDeserializationExceptionEvent.getCause())
                        .build());
            }

        };
    }
}
```

Messages in tcpIn() is sent to a @ServiceActivator method inside a separate @Component Class, which is structured like so :

```
@Component
public class TcpServiceActivator {

    @Autowired
    public TcpServiceActivator() {
    }


    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "tcpIn", outputChannel = "serviceChannel")
    public String service(byte[] byteMessage) {
     // Business Logic returns String Ack Response
    }
```

I don't have issues running a success scenario. My Tcp TestClient gets Ack response as expected.

However, when i try to simulate an exception, say  Deserializer Exception, The exception message is not sent back as a response to Tcp Client. 
I can see my Application Listener getting TcpDeserializationExceptionEvent and sending the message to exceptionEventChannel. The @ServiceActivator method handle(Message msg) also prints my exception message. But it never reaches the breakpoints (in a debug mode) inside MessageHandler method out(AbstractServerConnectionFactory cf).

I am struggling to understand whats going wrong. Thanks for any help in advance.

---

UPDATE : I notice that the Socket is closed due to exception before the response can be sent. I'm trying to figure out a way around this

SOLUTION UPDATE (12th Mar 2019) :

Courtesy of Gary, i edited my deserializer to return a message that can be traced by a @Router method and redirected to errorChannel. The ServiceActivator listening to errorchannel then sends the desired error message to outputChannel . This solution seems to work.

My deserializer method inside ByteArrayLengthPrefixSerializer returning a "special value" as Gary recommended, instead of the original inputStream message.

```
    public byte[] doDeserialize(InputStream inputStream, byte[] buffer) throws IOException {
        boolean isValidMessage = false;
        try {
            int messageLength = this.readPrefix(inputStream);
            if (messageLength > 0 && fillUntilMaxDeterminedSize(inputStream, buffer, messageLength)) {
                return this.copyToSizedArray(buffer, messageLength);
            }
            return EventType.MSG_INVALID.getName().getBytes(); 
        } catch (SoftEndOfStreamException eose) {
            return EventType.MSG_INVALID.getName().getBytes();
        }
    }
```

I also made a few new channels to accommodate my Router such that the flow is as follows :

Success flow
tcpIn (@Router) -> serviceChannel(@serviceActivator that holds business logic) -> outputChannel (@serviceActivator that sends response to client)

Exception flow
tcpIn (@Router) -> errorChannel(@serviceActivator that prepares the error Response message) -> outputChannel (@serviceActivator that sends response to client)

My @Router and 'errorHandling' @serviceActivator -

```
    @Router(inputChannel = "tcpIn", defaultOutputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public String messageRouter(byte[] byteMessage) {
        String unfilteredMessage = new String(byteMessage, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        System.out.println("------------------> "+unfilteredMessage);
        if (Arrays.equals(EventType.MSG_INVALID.getName().getBytes(), byteMessage)) {
            return "errorChannel";
        }
        return "serviceChannel";
    }


    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel", outputChannel = "outputChannel")
    public String errorHandler(byte[] byteMessage) {
        return Message.ACK_RETRY;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error channel is for handling exceptions that occur while processing a **message**. Deserialization errors occur before a **message** is created (the deserializer decodes the **payload** for the message).

Deserialization exceptions are fatal and, as you have observed, the socket is closed.

One option would be to catch the exception in the deserializer and return a "special" value that indicates a deserialization exception occurred, then check for that value in your main flow.

Comment: Thank you very much Gary! Let me try that and get back to you.

Comment: So that worked! I have updated the final solution to the question. Cheers!